# js to modify input based on another input AND print to .xls

Tags: javascript, html, var

I am trying to get id of `x` to change the value of a and print both values to `.xls`. I got part of it working properly (`x` will modify `a`) but it will not print to `.xls` properly. (says `[object]` instead of the value of variable `x` in the spreadsheet. 
Any help would be appreciated

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION id="Test"
                     applicationName"Test"
                     caption="yes" 
                     maximizeButton="no" 
                     minimizeButton="no" 
                     showInTaskbar="yes"
                     navigable="no"
                     singleInstance="yes"
                     scroll="no"
                     scrollFlat="yes" />
    </HTA:APPLICATION>
  </head>
<body>
  <form id="TEST">
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <input type="text" onblur="x1()" maxlength="2" id="X" />X <input type="text" maxlength="2" value="0" id="a" />a <br />
  </form>

  <script>
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var c = fso.CreateTextfile("z.xls",true);
    c.WriteLine("X  a");
    c.close();

    function x1() {
      var X         = document.getElementById("X");
      var a         = document.getElementById("a");

      if (X.value == 1) {
        a.value++;  
        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");  
        var c = fso.OpenTextfile("z.xls",8,true);   
        c.Writeline("" + X + "  " + a + "");
        c.close();
      } else {
        if (X.value == 2) {
          a.value--;    
          var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");    
          var c = fso.OpenTextfile("z.xls",8,true); 
          c.Writeline("" + X + "    " + a + "");    
          c.close();
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X` and `a` points to an `input` tags. You need to get the `value` property.

(Just like you did in the line: `if (X.value== 1)  {`)

Replace

```
c.Writeline(""+X+"    "+a+"");
```

To

```
c.Writeline(""+X.value+"    "+a.value+"");
```

Comment: shortly after i posted this, i realized that. much appreciated Mosh Few.